# Replace only 1 character from Lines with multiple same characters

Tags: regex, notepad++

I want to do something like this:
I have:

```
Field1: Data1:Data2
Field2: Data3

Field1: Data4:Data5
Field2: Data6
...
```

And I want to separete like this

```
Field1: Data1
Field3: Data2
Field2: Data3

Field1: Data4
Field3: Data5
Field2: Data6
```

The problem it's I can find a way to replace only the ":" between data and ignore the Field:

Edit: Sorry I'm not being explicit enough. The "Data" isn't really the text, can be anything very different so regex to target Data doesn't work.

Example:

```
FirstField: a:b
RandomField: abc
RandomField: ab

FirstField: 323:qwe
RandomField: abc123
```

Output:

```
FirstField: a
RegexField: b
RandomField: abc
RandomField: ab

FirstField: 323
RegexField: qwe
RandomField: abc123
```

Comment: Kinda like this? https://regex101.com/r/84vtwk/1

Comment: Do it in steps. First replace `: ` with `^ `. Then replace `:` with newline + `Field3: `. Then replace `^ ` back to `: `.

Comment: I believe you are looking for this [regex](https://regex101.com/r/84vtwk/2). It will capture all the instances of `Data[0-9]`, capture with or without `:` and ignore the `Field`.

Comment: I don't even understand the relationship of the source data to the destination.  Is it clear to everybody else?

Comment: So in the edit, you added an example, what would the output be?

Comment: Updated the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the future, please at least attempt to solve the issue yourself first. We appreciate some effort being made by those who ask questions.

That said, this is a simple conversion, it seems.

Find what:

```
:(\w+)$
```

Replace with:

```
\nField: \1
```

#### Showing it work

[image: Before replace]

[image: After replace]

Comment: I tried thats why I'm asking here. Updated my question.
Thanks for trying to help :)

Comment: Updated my answer to handle the general case instead. Will that do for you?

Comment: My bad, it works thanks. I guess it just doesn't in some regex websites. I really appreciate it

Comment: No problem! You had specifically added the `notepad++` tag, so I tailored the regex to work there. If you try this on a regex site, you need to enable the `multi line` flag. You can see that in action here: https://regex101.com/r/r6zwtm/1

Comment: Ahh. Thank you again